# How to display validation message under controls ? display issue

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Well i am working on knockout validations which is working fine . i have a display issue .

When there are errors those errors are displying beside the respective controls which makes my display go wild .

`**Fiddle link :**`  http://jsfiddle.net/JL26Z/29/

I need the error message  (ValidationMessage) display below the controls rather side of each control  .

refer the fiddle link and try to click submit .

Any suggestions are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [this](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Validation-Bindings)

you can customize display message like this

```
<p data-bind="validationMessage: someValue"></p>
```

Here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/raheelshan/JL26Z/31/

Moreover you can use jquery to hide default messages.

```
$('.validationMessage').hide()
```

EDITS :

http://jsfiddle.net/raheelshan/JL26Z/47/

The above fiddle will not display the message now. Instead it will only add a class to input element. Hope this helps.

Comment: bang on shan . Ty for help .  To go knockout way i used `ko.validation.init({ insertMessages: false });` which works fine . cheers

Comment: dude one more query if the error message is big displaying under also making my desigh go nuts . can we display error message inside textbox or watever as watermark with backcolor as red ? cheers .

Comment: you need to go through the docs i linked in the answer. See validation options. Must see `decorateInputElement`this will help

Comment: yes i looked but tried something like this `<input  type="text" data-bind="value:$data.Date,decorateInputElement:true"  />` expected on error i get color but nothing happened and i removed <p> tag .

Comment: given fiddle shows me just an alertbox and No css is applied . are you is this the right fiddle

Comment: amazing :) Ty for you continued help . god bless & have a good day . cheers